sequential game with stackelberg duopoly
Two firms, A and B, compete in a market selling identical goods. The
market demand curve is given by Q = 100 − P. Firms set prices PA
and PB. A chooses its price first, then observing it, B chooses the
price. Customers buy from whichever firm offers the cheaper price; if
both offer the same price, they buy from firm B.
Both firms have constant marginal costs of c1 and c2, respectively,
where c1, c2 ∈ [0, 20], and they are common knowledge. Both firms are
expected profit maximisers.
Q1.1
Describe the strategic interaction between the firms as a sequential
move game
